# Get date difference in days, hours, mins and secs (AM/PM date)

Tags: mysql, sql, date-difference

Trying to get date difference in `day - hours - mins - sec` from a string entry of date. Also the time entry is having `AM, PM`.
I am trying to use substring and converting it date time, but `AM - PM` is making it difficult.

I have: `06-OCT-15 09.30.20.000000 AM` and `06-OCT-15 09.45.20.000000 PM`

I am trying to get: `0 day(s) 12 hour(s) 15 min(s) 0 sec(s)`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Unfortunately too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes do date/time.)

Comment: What database do you use? mySQL, Oracle, Vertica, ...?

Comment: relational...i am using SQL server using dbVisualizer, a MySQL query will also do

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL answers will not be compatible here...

Comment: btw you cannot expect output as 9 hours, it would be 13 hours.

Comment: MySQL would be appreciable. Anyway will get idea from SQL query if SQL is given.

Comment: @rajeshmpanchal yeah thanks, just an example, edited

Comment: still there will be change in mins and secs as well.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of an RDBMS to this problem. Why not just use application level code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See below SQL Server query. I know this will work as I have some experience in this.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT CAST(
      DATEDIFF(
              DAY,
              '2015-10-06 08:00:00.00 AM',
              '2015-10-06 09:00:00.00 PM'
          ) AS 
          VARCHAR(1000)
      ) + ' day(s)' AS      Days,
      CAST(
          DATEDIFF(
              hh,
              '2015-10-06 08:00:00.00 AM',
              '2015-10-06 09:00:00.00 PM'
          ) AS VARCHAR(1000)
      ) + ' hour(s)' AS     Hours,
      CAST(
          DATEDIFF(
              mi,
              '2015-10-06 08:00:00.00 AM',
              '2015-10-06 09:00:00.00 PM'
          ) AS VARCHAR(1000)
      ) + ' min(s)' AS      Minutes,
      CAST(
          DATEDIFF(
              ss,
              '2015-10-06 08:00:00.00 AM',
              '2015-10-06 09:00:00.00 PM'
          ) AS VARCHAR(1000)
      ) + ' sec(s)' AS Seconds
)
SELECT Days + ' ' + Hours + ' ' + Minutes + ' ' + Seconds AS FullDifference
FROM   CTE
```

Comment: Thanks, helpful, it is calculating all the things separately. I want it to all together. There is overlapping of calculation. this way mins are included in mins and hours to.

Comment: edited, result will be all together.

Comment: thanks! i am not talking about concatenating, hope you understand by above comment.

Comment: can it be calculated altogether. It is calculating all things. (secs are calculated in mins also, mins are calculated in hours also) `13 hours` = `780 mins` = `46800 secs`. just `13 hours` we need, with telling that `mins` and `secs` are `0`

Answer (score 1):

it may help 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp

Example to get hours
you have to change you date string
like

select datediff(hour,CONVERT(datetime, '06-OCT-15 09:00:00.000 AM'),'06-OCT-15 08:00:00.000 PM') AS DiffDate
result:
11

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem seems to be a proper conversion of your datetime format to something that mySQL can work with.

Here you will find format options provided by mySQL to do this:

[www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Comment: The date data is formatted, just `CAST` will work. Need to get calculation right